Proof of Schwartz kernel theorem
In Melrose's proof of Schwartz kernel theorem here, I have trouble understand the last part of the proof. Basically, suppose $B:H^{-n}(\mathbb R^n_x)\to S(\mathbb R^m_y)$ is a continuous linear operator, and suppose that
$$K_B:(x,y)\mapsto B\left(\delta(\cdot-x)\right)(y)$$
is continuous. Then, it says that one can show that $K_B\in S'(\mathbb R^n_x\times\mathbb R^m_y)$ is the Schwartz kernel of $B|_{S\left(\mathbb R^N_x\right)}$.
I think this is essentially to show that
$$\int B\left(f\right) g(y)\;dy=\int\int B\left(\delta(\cdot-x)\right)(y)\;f(x)g(y)\;dxdy.$$
But I am not sure how to show that.
